# Complex regex to split up a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need some help with a regex conundrum pls. I'm still getting to grips with it all - clearly not an expert!

Eg. Say I have a complex string like so:

```
{something:here}{examp.le:!/?foo|bar}BLAH|{something/else:here}:{and:here\\}(.)}
```

First of all I want to split the string into an array by using the pipe, so it is effectively like:

```
{something:here}{examp.le:!/?foo|bar}BLAH
```

and

```
{something/else:here}:{and:here\\}(.)}
```

But notice that there is a pipe within the curly brackets to ignore... so need to work out the regex expression for this. I was using indexOf originally, but because I now have to take into account pipes being within the curly brackets, it complicates things.

And it isn't over yet! I also then need to split each string into separate parts by what is within the curly brackets and not. So I end up with 2 arrays containing:

**Array1**

```
{something:here}
{examp.le:!/?foo|bar}
BLAH
```

**Array2**

```
{something/else:here}
:
{and:here\\}(.)}
```

I added a double slash before the first closing curly bracket as a way of saying to ignore this one. But cannot figure out the regex to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all occurrences of "string in braces" or "just string", then iterate through found substrings and split when a pipe is encountered.

```
str = "{something:here}{examp.le:!/?foo|bar}BLAH|{something/else:here}:{and:here\\}(.)}"

var m = str.match(/{.+?}|[^{}]+/g)
var r = [[]];
var n = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
   var s = m[i];
   if(s.charAt(0) == "{" || s.indexOf("|") < 0)
       r[n].push(s);
   else {
      s = s.split("|");
      if(s[0].length) r[n].push(s[0]);
      r[++n] = [];
      if(s[1].length) r[n].push(s[1]);
   }
}
```

this expr will be probably better to handle escaped braces

```
  var m = str.match(/{?(\\.|[^{}])+}?/g
```

Comment: Cheers stereofrog. I like the approach :) It's almost there I think. It seems though when you are splitting the string into the 'm' array initially, you aren't ignoring the curly brace preceded by the \\. Any way to do this?

Comment: The changed regex line is missing the closing ")"

Comment: You are a genius mate. Exactly what I am looking for :) Thank so much. Been doing a lot of head scratching with this!