# Complex regex to split up a string - Part 2

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I posted this question a while back which was answered well:
[Complex regex to split up a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428889/complex-regex-to-split-up-a-string)

I know have a new conundrum related to it, and I'm really not getting anywhere...

Say I now have a string like this:

```
{foo.bar:/?a{3\}}{blah}
```

Using the code supplied in the previous post it does this:

```
{foo.bar:/?a
{3\}}
{blah}
```

I want it to do this:

```
{foo.bar:/?a{3\}}
{blah}
```

This is because now I have to deal with strings that don't have an escape before the second curly brace in the example. I need some code that can spot when to ignore certain opening curly braces. Eg. If reading along the string from left to right it sees the first opening curly brace, then when it sees the second opening curly brace it kinda says 'hang on, I haven't seen a valid closing curly brace yet, so I am going to ignore this'. Is this possible? I understand that it may not entirely possible using purely regex.

This is the initial part of the code I am using from the previous question which is causing the issue:

```
var m = str.match(/{?(\\.|[^{}])+}?/g);
```

Or another solution might be that when the user is typing & submitting the string beforehand, it slips in an escaping backslash without the user seeing it. The trouble with this is knowing which escaping backslashes to 'hide' again from the user...

Comment: First glance it looks like a job for recursion and/or iterative regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
var str = "{foo.bar:/?a{3\}}hello?{blah}world{blah2}";

var rgx = new RegExp(/}(?!})+[^{]*{/g); 

str = str.replace(rgx,"},{");

//document.write(str + "<br/>");

arr = str.split(",");

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

The key here is the regex `/}(?!})+[^{]*{/g`

`}` literal character match

`(?!})+` asserts that, following the previous match, at least one `}` isn't matched.

`[^{]*` matches any number of characters excluding `{`

`{` literal character match

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttKSj/6/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's a nice idea, and works in as far as the example I gave. However, I neglected to mention in this question that there could be anything between the fields, as my previous related question mentions. Eg. a string could look like this: {foo.bar:/?a{3\}}hello{blah}world{blah2}. I've voted this answer up though!

Comment: Have you solved your own question, then? Or should I revise my answer?

Comment: And what would happen to the text between the fields? Can you edit your question to show the output using the test string `{foo.bar:/?a{3\}}hello{blah}world{blah2}`?

Comment: @WastedSpace Check out my new answer. I think it does what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Some new work came up. Always the case. This really looks like it will do the job! Initial tests look great. Thanks for this :D

Comment: One more thing... I can work out how to create an array with all the content between {}, and an array with all the content between }{, but can't figure out how to combine the two in one array, preserving the order contained in the original string. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, got it. I separate then into the two arrays, then create an object  and add them all to the object using indexOf to give them all a unique id in the object. This retains the order...

Comment: Got a slight issue. There might be occasions where a string could look like this: {foo.bar:/?a{3\}hello}. It splits it into {foo.bar:/?a{3\} and hello}. Any ideas of tweaks to the regex? I'm pretty hopeless at complex regex... Thanks!